# how to properly implement Observer in python when the observer is [should be] destroyed

Tags: python, observer-pattern, reference-cycle

I'm implementing an observer-observable pattern in python:

This is the Observable class:

```
class Observable(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.observers = []

    def set(self, value):
        old = self.value
        self.value = value
        self.notifyObservers(old, self.value)

    def get(self):
        return self.value

    def addObserver(self, o):
        self.observers.append(o)

    def removeObserver(self, o):
        if o in self.observers:
            self.observers.remove(o)

    def notifyObservers(self, old, new):
        for o in self.observers:
            o.valueChanged(old, new)
```

and this is an observer:

```
class Observer(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        self.foo.addObserver(self)

    def __del__(self):
        print('Observer.__del__ called')
        self.foo.removeObserver(self)

    def valueChanged(self, old, new):
        print('foo changed from %s to %s' % (old, new))
```

The code works as expected.

But I need the `Observer` to be destroyed (i.e. when it goes unreferenced, it should remove itself from the list of observers in the `Observable` object).

The problem is that with this code, `Observer.__del__` never gets called if the `Observer` is in the list of observers of some `Observable` object.

Note that I don't necessarily destroy the `Observer` explicitly, it will also go unreferenced because of variable assignment, thus calling `removeObserver()` explicitly prior to destruction **is not viable**.

If I comment out `self.foo.addObserver(self)`, then there are no additional references to `Observer`, and calling `del` on it will call `Observer.__del__`.

The testcase for this scenario is:

```
foo = Observable(23)
bar = Observer(foo)
foo.set(44)
bar = None
foo.set(1)
```

it has two outcomes:

- if `self.foo.addObserver(self)` is not commented out, it prints `foo changed from 23 to 44` and `foo changed from 44 to 1`
- if `self.foo.addObserver(self)` is commented out, it prints `Observer.__del__ called`

Comment: Have you looked at weakrefs? Weak references are designed to solve exactly this problem and have been a feature of Python since 2.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that weak reference will solve your problem.
You change the observers to manage [weak-references](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html), e.g, by replacing the `list` in a `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary`, or by implementing some other weak-reference container. BTW, using a hashed type, such as a dictionary, will also be better than a list since removing an observer will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: (changed `Observable.observers` to `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary`)

```
class Observable(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.observers = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()

    def set(self, value):
        old = self.value
        self.value = value
        self.notifyObservers(old, self.value)

    def get(self):
        return self.value

    def addObserver(self, o):
        self.observers[o] = 1

    def removeObserver(self, o):
        del self.observers[o]

    def notifyObservers(self, old, new):
        for o in self.observers:
            o.valueChanged(old, new)
```

Also, it is not required to call `.removeObserver(self)` in the observer's destructor.